# Unable to select Un Ordered List of 2 similar drop down values through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I’m trying to automate and select the drop down values.
2 fields are having same drop down values (i.e.). Yes and No and both field has similar HTML code . So unable to find unique Xpath in order to click on second field and it is throwing an org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException exception. Since the tag name is not SELECT, so I couldn’t use SELECT Class.

HTML Code:

**1st Field**

```
    <table id="ssl" class="x-field dropdown x-form-item x-box-item x-field-default x-vbox-form-item x-form-dirty" style="margin: 0px; width: 660px; table-layout: fixed; left: 9px; top: 36px;" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr id="ssl-inputRow">
         <td id="ssl-labelCell" class="x-field-label-cell" style="" halign="left" width="385" valign="top">
            <label id="ssl-labelEl" class="x-form-item-label x-form-item-label-left" for="ssl-inputEl" style="width:380px;margin-right:5px;">Use SSL to connect to NetScaler </label>
         </td>
         <td id="ssl-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body x-form-trigger-wrap-focus" colspan="2" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
            <table id="ssl-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td id="ssl-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div id="ext-gen1668" class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
                        <input id="ssl-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" name="ssl" readonly="readonly" style="width: 100%; -moz-user-select: text;" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" type="text">
                     </td>
                     <td id="ext-gen1667" class="x-trigger-cell" style="width:22px" valign="top">
                        <div id="ext-gen1666" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**2nd Field:**

```
<table id="isDiscovery" class="x-field dropdown x-form-item x-box-item x-field-default x-vbox-form-item x-form-dirty" style="margin: 0px; width: 660px; table-layout: fixed; left: 9px; top: 67px;" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr id="isDiscovery-inputRow">
         <td id="isDiscovery-labelCell" class="x-field-label-cell" style="" halign="left" width="385" valign="top">
            <label id="isDiscovery-labelEl" class="x-form-item-label x-form-item-label-left" for="isDiscovery-inputEl" style="width:380px;margin-right:5px;">Discover StoreFront hosts using this NetScaler </label>
         </td>
         <td id="isDiscovery-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body" colspan="2" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
            <table id="isDiscovery-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td id="isDiscovery-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div id="ext-gen1671" class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
                        <input id="isDiscovery-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" name="isDiscovery" readonly="readonly" style="width: 100%; -moz-user-select: text;" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" type="text">
                     </td>
                     <td id="ext-gen1670" class="x-trigger-cell" style="width:22px" valign="top">
                        <div id="ext-gen1669" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Tried Xpath (but it is failing to select 2nd field)

1st field xpath:

```
.//*[@id='ssl-inputEl']//following::div[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[2][contains(text(), 'No')]

.//*[@id='ssl-inputEl’]//following::div[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[1][contains(text(), ‘Yes’)]

.//*[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[1][contains(text(), 'Yes')]

.//*[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[2][contains(text(), 'No')]
```

**2nd field xpath:**

```
.//*[@id='isDiscovery-inputEl']//following::div[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[2][contains(text(), 'No')]

.//*[@id='isDiscovery-inputEl']//following::div[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[1][contains(text(), ‘Yes’)]

.//*[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[1][contains(text(), 'Yes')]

.//*[contains(@id,'boundlist-')]/div/ul/li[2][contains(text(), 'No')]
```

Comment: The fields look to be tables? Doesn't seem to align with your Xpath?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really find any `(@id,'boundlist-')` or `[contains(text(), 'Yes')]` or `[contains(text(), 'No')]` in the shared `HTML`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Actually Fire path generated xpath ".//*[@id='boundlist-1058-listEl']/ul/li[1]". Since ID are dynamic, I have written xpath with contains and text. This is what fire path shows, "<li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected x-boundlist-item-over" role="option">Yes</li>"

Comment: @smit9234 14 Xpath is matching and click for first field, but in case of second field, it is not, because both field has same value

Comment: For Yes and No drop down values, "<div id="boundlist-1088" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default" tabindex="-1" style="left: 867px; top: 279px; height: auto; width: 275px; z-index: 19001;">
<div id="boundlist-1088-outerEl" class="x-boundlist-outer-ct" style="overflow:auto">
<div id="boundlist-1088-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul>
<li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected x-boundlist-item-over" role="option">Yes</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">No</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>"